# How to perform copy to clipboard in lightning component?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-aura-components, javascript, lightning

I have  button `onclick` of that button the text present in the text area should be copied.In visualforce im able to perform this operation using `document.execCommand('copy')` but in lightning it says the function in not available.

```
copyText:function(component,event,helper)
{           
    var doc = component.find("text").get("v.value");
    console.log('doc=='+doc);
    doc.queryCommandSupported('copy');
    doc.execCommand('copy');

},
```

This i have used in the component,

```
<lightning:textarea aura:id="text"  name="myTextArea" label="Input 
Text" maxlength="300" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently I do not have option to select text of `lightning:textarea` as only `focus` and `showHelpMessageIfInvalid` methods are available for [lightning:textarea](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:textarea/specification). You can  use html tag `textarea`, as proxy `SecureElement` object supports `select` [method](http://documentation.auraframework.org/lockerApiTest/index.app?aura.mode=DEV)  and proxy `SecureDocument` supports both `queryCommandSupported` and `execCommand`.

**Component**

```
<textarea id="text" value="Hello SF" maxlength="300" />  
<lightning:button variant="base" label="Copy to Clipboard" onclick="{!c.copyText}"/>
```

**Controller**

```
({
    copyText: function(cmp, event, helper) {
        var textareaElement = document.getElementById('text');
        textareaElement.select();
        document.queryCommandSupported('copy')
        document.execCommand('copy');
        textareaElement.blur();
    }
})
```